# decreasing buffer time for html5 video streaming

Tags: streaming, html5-video

I'm pushing a live ogg theora/vorbis stream to the browser using icecast and displayed using an HTML5 container. The only problem is that the browser insists on having a video buffer for smooth playback, which adds to the latency. Chrome seems to buffer about three seconds while firefox buffers about five. Is there any way to decrease this buffer length and make the playback closer to real-time?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid smooth playback?

Comment: I don't want to avoid smooth playback, I want zero latency. This is pretty much a moot point now since I discovered webRTC which will do what I want. (real-time video conferencing) It's not released yet though, unfortunately.